# How to add a claim of type "StringCollection" in ad b2c custom policies

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I want to add two output claims of type "StringCollection",
1. country (eg: US, UK etc)
2. group (eg: XX, XY, XZ)

Need to save this data when user sign up and need to add these to token

I have created the following claim type:

```
<ClaimType Id="extension_countries">
        <DisplayName>Countries</DisplayName>
        <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Country list</UserHelpText>
 </ClaimType>
```

and transformation:

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateCountriesFromCountry" TransformationMethod="AddItemToStringCollection">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" TransformationClaimType="item" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_countries" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_countries" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

When i added
        
to the RelyingParty's "OutputClaims" it is showing error 
"The data type 'StringCollection' is not supported for extension property 'extension_countries' in technical profile"

Answer (score 2):

The error is probably due to the underlying limitation of AAD Graph API extension properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions#extension-data-types--

Types available:

- Binary
- Boolean
- DateTime
- Integer
- LargeInteger
- String

So you can't create an extension property that is a string collection.

Comment: But we have "otherMails", a string collection in starter pack "https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L192"

Comment: It's a built-in property on the User, not an extension https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity

Comment: Understood, so there is no other way to create a string collection?

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, write own REST function to convert the collection to a string and vice versa provided your string size does not exceed 256 chars (I think that's the max).

Answer (score 1):

Where you went wrong is trying to define a claim that will be already coming out of a call to read AAD. Create a new claim and just don't expose `extension_countries` as an output claim.

First you create a new ClaimType

```xml
      <ClaimType Id="Countries">
        <DisplayName>Countries</DisplayName>
        <DataType>stringCollection</DataType> 
        <UserHelpText>A list of countries for user</UserHelpText>
        <!-- ... removed for brevity -->
      </ClaimType>
```

Then you create a claims transformation

```xml
     <ClaimsTransformation Id="CountriesClaimFromExtensionCountries" TransformationMethod="StringSplit">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_countries" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
        <InputParameter DataType="string" Id="delimiter" Value="," />
          </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Countries" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
```

During your user journey there should be a step where you read from AAD using the user's object id

```xml
<!-- NOTE: This is an example step, for your specific use case it maybe different, but whatever the step is that reads from AAD and gets the extension_countries attribute, do it there. 
          in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

Update that technical profile to use the claims tranformation you just created.

```xml
<!-- The following technical profile is used to read data after user authenticates. -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Optional claims -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <!-- NOTE: assuming you already added this -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_countries" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <!-- NOTE: This is where you add the reference to the claims tranformation -->
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
              <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CountriesClaimFromExtensionCountries"/>
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Then in your relying party... Make sure the claim is outputted.

```xml
<RelyingParty>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
    <!-- NOTE: new output claim, other output claims are omitted for brevity -->    
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Countries" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
```

Comment: there it will error out though if extension_countries is empty or not returned. I would probably create a new step in the user journey after the AAD read step and check if extensions_countries is there then run the claims tranformation.

Comment: in the end, i decided it wasn't really worth the extra effort to take a comma delimited string and make it a stringCollection that would later be serialized as a json array. As a comma delimited string can quickly be converted where its consumed into an array. Keeping policies clean and simple is more important in my perspective.

Comment: you are the boss) Thank you a lot for such detailed answer! Helped in lot in understanding how custom policies works.

Answer (score 0):

ADB2C Identity experience framwork validates the claimtype when you upload the relying party policy xml file, It would work fine if you change the claimtype datatype from stringCollection to string and upload it, then upload the relying party policy. And then you can change the claimtype datatype from string to stringCollection and upload the policy. This time everything should work as intended. This way you can return string collection as a claim type using IEF in ADB2C. Hope this helps.

```
<ClaimType Id="extension_countries">
        <DisplayName>Countries</DisplayName>
        <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Country list</UserHelpText>
 </ClaimType>
```